# My images are breaking my android app

Tags: android, image, gridview

I followed the tutorial on http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html .
The app works fine but when I use my own images that I've made with Illustrator, for some reason, the app displays a blank page and then crashes soon afterwards. Why does this happen? What kind of images does ImageView display?

Comment: how big are your image files? bigger than 1024 x 1024? I think at a certain size , some mobile phones don't accept/like to render them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have memory leaks. This happens very often when loading big images. [Here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) you can find good tips and two great pieces of code that could help you to solve this issue.

Comment: What would be considered a "large" image? The image is 580 KB, 250x250. It's basically a green square. The code is identical to the tutorial, with the only difference being the images.